# Как исправить 'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Система `Windows 10`. Установил `MariaDB 10.2`, загрузил загрузил в неё sql-дамп, нужный мне для работы. Далее, когда я пытаюсь подключиться к базе данных через `Intellij IDEA`, я получаю предупреждение:

```
Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 20, found 21. The table is probably corrupted.
```

Самоё распространённое решение в интернете, это использование следующей команды:

```
mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

Однако, это не срабатывает, возникает ошибка и база данных падает. Вот лог выполнения команды:

```
Phase 1/7: Checking and upgrading mysql database
Processing databases
mysql
mysql.column_stats                                 OK
mysql.columns_priv                                 OK
mysql.db                                           OK
mysql.event                                        OK
mysql.func                                         OK
mysql.global_priv                                  OK
mysql.gtid_slave_pos                               OK
mysql.help_category                                OK
mysql.help_keyword                                 OK
mysql.help_relation                                OK
mysql.help_topic                                   OK
mysql.host                                         OK
mysql.index_stats                                  OK
mysql.innodb_index_stats                           OK
mysql.innodb_table_stats                           OK
mysql.plugin                                       OK
mysql.proc                                         OK
mysql.procs_priv                                   OK
mysql.proxies_priv                                 OK
mysql.roles_mapping                                OK
mysql.servers                                      OK
mysql.table_stats                                  OK
mysql.tables_priv                                  OK
mysql.time_zone                                    OK
mysql.time_zone_leap_second                        OK
mysql.time_zone_name                               OK
mysql.time_zone_transition                         OK
mysql.time_zone_transition_type                    OK
mysql.transaction_registry                         OK
Phase 2/7: Installing used storage engines... Skipped
Phase 3/7: Fixing views
mysql.user                                         OK
Phase 4/7: Running 'mysql_fix_privilege_tables'
ERROR 1347 (HY000) at line 143: 'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE
ERROR 1267 (HY000) at line 145: Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,COERCIBLE) and (cp866_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'
ERROR 1347 (HY000) at line 146: 'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE
ERROR 1348 (HY000) at line 158: Column 'Grant_priv' is not updatable
ERROR 1347 (HY000) at line 161: 'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE
ERROR 1347 (HY000) at line 166: 'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE
ERROR 1267 (HY000) at line 202: Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,COERCIBLE) and (cp866_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'
ERROR 1347 (HY000) at line 203: 'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE
ERROR 1348 (HY000) at line 211: Column 'Show_db_priv' is not updatable
ERROR 1347 (HY000) at line 212: 'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE
ERROR 1347 (HY000) at line 222: 'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE
ERROR 1347 (HY000) at line 225: 'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE
ERROR 1347 (HY000) at line 227: 'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE
ERROR 1347 (HY000) at line 231: 'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE
ERROR 1347 (HY000) at line 233: 'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE
ERROR 1267 (HY000) at line 332: Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,COERCIBLE) and (cp866_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'
ERROR 1347 (HY000) at line 337: 'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE
ERROR 1347 (HY000) at line 338: 'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE
ERROR 1347 (HY000) at line 343: 'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE
ERROR 1347 (HY000) at line 344: 'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE
ERROR 1348 (HY000) at line 345: Column 'Create_view_priv' is not updatable
ERROR 1267 (HY000) at line 347: Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,COERCIBLE) and (cp866_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'
ERROR 1347 (HY000) at line 352: 'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE
ERROR 1347 (HY000) at line 353: 'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE
ERROR 1347 (HY000) at line 358: 'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE
ERROR 1347 (HY000) at line 359: 'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE
ERROR 1348 (HY000) at line 364: Column 'Create_routine_priv' is not updatable
ERROR 1347 (HY000) at line 367: 'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE
ERROR 1347 (HY000) at line 368: 'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE
ERROR 1267 (HY000) at line 370: Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,COERCIBLE) and (cp866_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'
ERROR 1347 (HY000) at line 371: 'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE
ERROR 1347 (HY000) at line 372: 'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE
ERROR 1348 (HY000) at line 373: Column 'Create_user_priv' is not updatable
ERROR 1267 (HY000) at line 484: Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,COERCIBLE) and (cp866_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'
ERROR 1347 (HY000) at line 485: 'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE
ERROR 1347 (HY000) at line 486: 'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE
ERROR 1348 (HY000) at line 487: Column 'Event_priv' is not updatable
ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 550: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 551: MySQL server has gone away
...
ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 661: MySQL server has gone away
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

Я не понимаю, каким образом решить ошибку `'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE` *(а по-видимому обновление ломается из-за неё)*. Команда также не работает, если я пытаюсь выполнить её с флагом `--force`. [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58969360/14614707) указано решение, но оно также не помогает. После выполнения команды `REPAIR VIEW mysql.user;` поведение остаётся прежним.

Каким образом я могу решить проблему `'mysql.user' is not BASE TABLE`?

Comment: Судя по всему, дамп у тебя полный, включающий системные БД. И ты не глядя втащил на сервер вообще всё, включая системные таблицы, причём на неподходящую версию сервера. Это - задница. Можешь сносить сервер и ставить его заново. И либо получать новый дамп, без системных БД, либо выпиливать системные БД из имеющегося дампа. Никакие фиксы, апгрейды, репэйры и сейфы не помогут.

Comment: @Akina звучит грустно. Мне кажется, что раньше я как-то справлялся с этим, сейчас просто пытаюсь БД поднять на новом компьютере. Попробую установить дамп без системных БД, посмотрю как оно.

Comment: *Мне кажется, что раньше я как-то справлялся с этим* Если накатить более старую версию служебной таблицы, причём апгрейд версии от этой старой до текущей может быть выполнен за один проход - это лечится. У тебя же, как я понимаю, ситуация обратная, в этом случае такая операция не поможет, а про утилиту mysql_downgrade я как-то не слышал... И уж совсем плохо, если на Машку наливается дамп Муськи.